# If the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent is the following conclusion correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it correct that, if the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent the sequence $(\frac{1}{a_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ isn't convergent? I'm not sure hope somebody can help.

Comment: What about $a_n = 1$?

Comment: Well, you are absolutely right. Sorry for that dumb question.

Comment: This should only be true if $(a_n) \to 0$ otherwise you have if $(a_n)\to a\neq 0$ that $(1/a_n) \to 1/a$.

Comment: I think that you've mixed convergence of sequence with convergence of its sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(a_n)$ does *not* converge to $0$ (and no term is equal to $0$, which we can then assume WLOG, because then we skip some finite number of terms) but to some $a \neq 0$, then $(\frac{1}{a_n})_n$ converges to $\frac{1}{a}$ by continuity of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

If the limit *is* equal to $0$, then the sequence $(\frac{1}{a_n})$ is unbounded (and possibly even undefined for many, if not all, $n$) and hence non-convergent.

Answer (score 3):

If $(a_n)$ is convergent, then you can't say anything about the convergence of $(\frac{1}{a_n})$. For example, the constant sequence $(x_n) :=(1,1,1,1,1,,\ldots )$ converges and so does $(\frac{1}{x_n})$. But, the sequence $y_n):= (\frac{1}{n})$ converges, but $(\frac{1}{y_n}) = (n)$ does not converge.

Comment: You can say something, depending on the limit, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, of course.+1

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct for example take the convergent sequence $a_n\equiv 1$ then $\frac{1}{a_n}\equiv 1$ is convergent also.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are thinking of an infinite **series**, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$.  It is true that if that series converges then $a_n$ must go to 0 as n goes to infinity.  In that case, $\frac{1}{a_n}$ **cannot** go to 0 and the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ does not converge.